# Custom colorRamp for Heatmap R when only having 1 data point

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

So I need several heat maps and to not overcrowd my app I'm separating them into smaller heatmaps. The problem is that I cannot get the colors to show up on the colorbar. I made a custom colorRamp and am using zmin and zmax but it isn't working. Can someone please tell me what to do, I have scoured the web for a while and nothing. Help would be obliged.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
data<-data.frame(Start_Period=c("Early Afternoon"),Meeting_Days=c("MTWR"),Average=c(23))


    ui <-fluidPage(
      plotlyOutput("test")
    )

    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
      output$test<-renderPlotly({

        plot_ly(data,
                x = data$Meeting_Days, y =data$Start_Period,
                z = data$Average, type = "heatmap",
                hoverinfo='text',
                zauto=FALSE,
                zmin=0,
                zmax=80,
                colorbar=list(
                  title='Average Enrollment'
                ),
                colors = colorRamp(c('#700001',
                                     '#c10001',
                                     '#eff6ff',
                                     '#9ae7f3',
                                     '#1D7DBB')),
                text=paste("Average Enrollment:",data$Average_Enrollment)
        )%>%layout(margin=list(l = 110,pad = 2 ))
      })  

    })

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is an example of what I'm working with ideally I would like the colorbar to have all the colors within the colorRamp and for the heatmap to follow it. The color it has chosen is the #eff6ff which is the middle one and paying no attention to the rest.

Comment: @MarcoSandri yeah sometimes the data only has 1 cell. Works well for multiple cells but not for a single one and that where I am stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `ggplotly` and the same problem occurs. So maybe you could trick it. You could add an `if else` statement in your `renderPlotly({})` argument. If the number of rows is 1 you could add a row with a very small number in place of average (I replaced 23 with 1). Hope it helps!

```
ui <-fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("test")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$test<-renderPlotly({

    if (nrow(data) <= 1) {

      data2 <- data
      data3 <- rbind(data, data2)
      data3[2, 3] <- 1

    } else  {

      data3 <- data

    } 


    plot_ly(data3,
            x = ~Meeting_Days, y =~Start_Period,
            z = ~Average, type = "heatmap",
            hoverinfo='text',
            zauto=FALSE,
            zmin=0,
            zmax=80,
            colorbar=list(
              title='Average Enrollment'
            ),
            colors = colorRamp(c('#700001',
                                 '#c10001',
                                 '#eff6ff',
                                 '#9ae7f3',
                                 '#1D7DBB')),
            text=paste("Average Enrollment:",data$Average_Enrollment)
    )%>%layout(margin=list(l = 110,pad = 2 ))

  })  

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```